# How can I add “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” to all the response headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am running an ASP.NET MVC 3 website on IIS. Is there a flag in web.config or something similar that can do this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As long as you're using IIS 7 or above, it's as simple as adding it to your web.config.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or you can add them using the IIS Management GUI, or even command line. Take a look at http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

Comment: I also found that IIS automatically adds this info to the web.config deployed.

Comment: @AbbasFaisal I had to configure this manually. IIS doesn't automatically do this for you.

Comment: For on IIS 10, I had to edit `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

Comment: Woks perfect for me in ASP.Net, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This question originates from MVC 3, but as this problem is still relevant in ASP.NET Core, I'll let myself propose a solution for the recent versions:

```
 public static IApplicationBuilder UseNoSniffHeaders(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
 {
     return builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
     {
         context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
         await next();
     });
 }
```

Then simply add this in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseNoSniffHeaders();
```

The beauty of this approach is that it makes it independent from your web server and deployment process. At the same time you may need to extend this solution if you want it to apply to static files as well.

Comment: Trying to pass my CASA tier 2 per google's new restricted scopes and I was flagged for this missing header. This method is a perfect remedy for any little missing header alerts.

Answer (score 1):

In case whenever you deploy new application and its replacing the web.config file. its better to add the configuration IIS site level as below.

1. Click on site and select the 'HTTP response headers".
2. Click on 'add' on left side corner and add the name and value as below.

> name: X-Content-Type-Options
> value: nosniff

[image]

The nosniff response header is a way to keep a website more secure. Security researcher Scott Helme describes it like this: “It prevents Google Chrome and Internet Explorer from trying to mime-sniff the content-type of a response away from the one being declared by the server.