# Check if the original content of files is not a script or exe content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I am working on file upload and download web App using .net mvc C# APIs and I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948535/5470794) to consider some file security points and I have two questions:

1. According to the **Filetypes** point particularly this statement

   > It's best if the application uses some real content discovery to find
   >   out if the uploaded file is actually an allowed filetype.

   I want to check if the user uploads an .exe, .dll or "html containing js code"
   file as renamed text file but i don't know how to do that.
2. According to **Content sniffing** point, I have added

   > X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

   To my api `web.config` file flowing this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24142764/5470794)
   but when i upload html page including java script code it uploads and download without any interruption, so how to prevent my app from uploading and downloading these kinds of files.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ideas here (theoretical and practical):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160129/c-malicious-file-upload-to-server
https://www.computerweekly.com/answer/File-upload-security-best-practices-Block-a-malicious-file-upload

I personally would suggest to white-list the extensions that will be allowed to upload, instead of black-listing potentially dangerous extensions.

Comment: I already have a white list extensions but extension checking only is not enough , may someone upload .exe content as .txt extension , so i need content checking also

Comment: Both sites give you ideas, like renaming the files regardless (at least temporarily), putting them in some restricted folders, and the most important one, virus scan all the received files.